# Display web form in tooltip

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, calendar, tooltip

I have used calendar control of ASP.NET. When I move on any date than it will be display tooltip , in which I can show my another aspx page. And in that aspx page there is gridview.

How can I display tooltip which contains aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Track one**

- Use a div to position your element as a tooltip.
- In that div use an iframe in which you can load your aspx page.

**Track two**

you can use div without iframe and use jquery to pull data from server against hovered date and render that data into that div at runtime using `$("#divID").html()` function.

Personally I would recommend track two because here page life cycle is eliminated and data would load much faster which is required for a tooltip,

only demerit with track two is that its a little complicated because you will have to create your design at runtime using `document.createElement()` and other functions like that.

You could get some help from [Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1172025.aspx) maybe.

Comment: yes,  I have already tried with Iframe, it gives very slow response

Comment: Try using track two then, If you face any problem than SO is here for you.